# Proper way to define a resource routes in Ember?

Tags: routes, ember.js

In the guides, I can see 2 ways to define the routes of a resource, and I was wondering what's the one I should use, and why?

---

Found here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
});
```

---

Found here: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function(){
    this.route("post", { path: "/:post_id" });
  });
});
```

I found it weird to have to define 2 resources, `posts` and `post`, when it's actually just a `Post` resource.

Comment: The post that got be over the "when a route/resource" http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/02/01/ember-dot-js-router-and-template-naming-convention/

Comment: I actually read this entire blog a couple of days ago, but since I had not experienced it myself, I forgot. This actually answer my question pretty well. Wouldn't you say that the 2nd example is not "correct" if you follow the definition given on the ember guides or in this article? Not sure why they use route for post. Maybe it was just for the example. Add this link as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe when you do it like this

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function(){
    this.route("post", { path: "/:post_id" });
  });
});
```

it renders the post template inside the {{outlet}} of the posts template..

when you do it this way

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
});
```

the posts template doesn't render when you visit /posts/:post_id

Comment: Yep, you're right. Why do they use route instead of resource for "post" in your first example though?

Comment: From http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ : 

You should use this.resource for URLs that represent a noun, and this.route for URLs that represent adjectives or verbs modifying those nouns.

Comment: A resource called posts actually creates two routes, PostsRoute and PostsIndexRoute. the PostsIndexRoute is rendered inside the PostsRoute outlet